# Перемешивание массива в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый всем день. Решил написать пятнашки на Unity3D, но застрял и приуныл. Хотел реализовать рандомное перемешивание пятнашек, но не могу понять где ошибаюсь, так что выручайте.

Вот так я планирую чтобы они у меня выглядели в начале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так я хочу их перемешать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итог при любых моих попытках реализовать всегда такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что часть фишек всегда залазит друг на друга.

```
public class Primer : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject[] plastinka;
    private GameObject[] newObject;
    private Transform[] plastinkatransform;


    void Start () {
        newObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Plastinka");

        plastinka = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Plastinka");

        plastinkatransform = new Transform[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < plastinka.Length; i++)
        {

           plastinkatransform[i] = plastinka[i].transform;

          }

        Shuffle(plastinkatransform);

      //  var random = new System.Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
      // plastinka = plastinka.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();

       for (int i = 0; i < plastinka.Length; i++)
        {
         newObject[i].transform.position = plastinkatransform[i].position;}

    void Shuffle(Transform[] deck)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
        {
            Transform temp = deck[i];
            int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, deck.Length);
            deck[i] = deck[randomIndex];
            deck[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вы перемешиваете сразу объекты? Может я чего не понимаю в юнити, но сдается мне перемешать простой двумерный массив чисел и на его основе расставить объекты несколько проще. 2. Вы в курсе, что если просто рандомно расставить фишки - головоломка может не иметь решения? Просто переставьте местами 14 и 15 (остальные оставляем в исходном положении по порядку) и попробуйте собрать. Перемешивать пятнашки нужно тем же способом, что и собирать их, элемент случайности может быть в выборе одной из 2-4х фишек для сдвига, в зависимости от положения свободной клетки.

Comment: Есть конечно и обходной маневр - существует чисто математический критерий наличия решения, можно взять полностью случайное заполнение и после проверки на наличие решения внести корректировку. Это может быть проще, а может быть и нет, зависит от ваших знаний.

Comment: Я создал 2 массива, 1 массив перемешиваю, так как при перемешивании меняется его transform.position. Так как во втором массиве имеется первоначальный transform.position, я беру его игровой объект задаю ему новый вектор позиций из перемешенного массива, по идее должен полностью  расставить.рандомно. Но результат всегда такой.

Comment: С перемешиванием вроде все ок, ну кроме отсутствия гарантий наличия решения. Мне что-то не нравится в передаче позиций, но мои знания тут кончаются и начинается юнити =( Надо что ли уже самому его руками пощупать...

Comment: А зачем ты вообще объекты юнити трогаешь, перемешай его в коде. А то я так понимаю ты пытаешься перемешать сами объекты которые на сцене у тебя визуализируют массив. Мешай в коде, можешь даже начинать с полностью собранного массива и по шагам, следуя определенному алгоритму, мешать элементы массива с последующей анимацией на сцене.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии, в итоге оказалось, что нужно перемешать массив состоящий из Vector3. Видно я не полностью понимаю как работает GameObject.transform.

Answer (score 1):

Я как-то тоже делал пятнашки, но рандомизацию я делал путем случайного количества движений случайных фишек, что имеют свободную клетку соседа. Т.е. перемешивал собранное состояние

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за комментарии, в итоге оказалось, что нужно перемешать массив состоящий из Vector3. Видно я не полностью понимаю как работает GameObject.transform.